# How to set user search and filter preference on account registration

Tags: entities, users

I'm bulding a dating site, and I want users to have default search and filtering capabilities.

The field in question is gender.

I want users to be able to choose default search parameter to male or female. So when they access the view, it will only show them males or females, depending on their choice at registration and user account profile settings.

I'm pretty sure core functionality can do something like that, but I can't figure out what kind of settings to use...

I'm attaching the image to demonstrate what I am trying to acheive with an example from another website, the fields "I am a man" >> "I want to find a woman" 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use views [global filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter) to achieve this functionality. What you set in profile2 field you will be get it globally in views too. In view you need to add only filter for that value.

Another way you can add relationship of user profile and add in contextual filer of logged in user value of interest in gender field.

Comment: I appreciate both answers above, but I'm afraid I don't quite understand...could anybody clarify these 2 options in a little clearer terms if possible? Thanks